# How to convert Data Frame to Term Document Matrix in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, tf-idf

I have a table (Data frame) `myTable` with a single column as follows:

```
         sentence
1      it is a window
2      My name is john doe
3      Thank you
4      Good luck
.
.
.
```

I want to convert it to a Term Document Matrix in R. I did this:

```
tdm_s <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(DataframeSource(myTable)))
```

but I got this error:

```
Error: all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE
```

I googled and couldn't find anything. How can I do this conversion?

Comment: What sort of input does `DataframeSource()` expect? Is `myTable` of that type?

Comment: `myTable` is a `dataframe`. Besides, I passed `Corpus(DataframeSource(myTable))` to the `TermDocumentMatrix()`, not `myTable`. @AkselA

Comment: Sure, but what kind of data.frame. And in what function does the error occur, is it inherited?

Comment: When I run this `DataframeSource(myTable)` the error occurs. @AkselA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do as below to convert into Term Document Matrix:

```
## Your sample data
myTable <- data.frame(sentence = c("it is a window", "My name is john doe", "Thank you", "Good luck"))

## You need to use VectorSource before using Corpus
library(tm)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(myTable$sentence))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)

inspect(tdm)
#<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 8, documents: 4)>>
#Non-/sparse entries: 8/24
#Sparsity           : 75%
#Maximal term length: 6
#Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
#Sample             :
#         Docs
#Terms   1 2 3 4
#doe     0 1 0 0
#good    0 0 0 1
#john    0 1 0 0
#luck    0 0 0 1
#name    0 1 0 0
#thank   0 0 1 0
#window  1 0 0 0
#you     0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Its maybe because you are using `DataframeSource` instead of using of  `VectorSource`. Since the error says matching of `doc_id` and `doc` is not non `NA`. I am guessing id and then empty document is causing problem when you use `DataframeSource`.

Comment: @Patris: I tried hinting at it gently, but please read [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-3/topics/DataframeSource). It has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the Quanteda package (which is very good)...

```
require(quanteda)
# Your sample data 
# Important to make sure the sentence variable is not converted to type factor
myTable <- data.frame(sentence = c("it is a window", "My name is john doe", "Thank you", "Good luck"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
newcorpus <- corpus(myTable, text_field = "sentence") # you have to tell it the name of the text field
# lots of options to dfm read the help pages
newdfm <- dfm(newcorpus, remove_punct = TRUE, remove = stopwords("english"), stem = TRUE)
newdfm
```